# Empty reference.cs file when upgrading a project of from VS2008 to VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, visual-studio-2008

I have a project in VS 2008 which has some Service Reference in it. When I try to upgrade to project from VS2008 to VS2010 [while framework remain same.  i.e. 3.5] my reference .cs file get empty. I have seen a some solution mentioning  Un-checking the "Reuse Types" worked for some one but in my case it doesn't. If even I try in VS2008 to unchecked it and try to compile my reference.cs get empty.
i doesn't want's to refresh the service reference as at the moment i doesn't have access to exposed service. Just want to make my application compilable in VS 2010.

Comment: Copy the code in the reference.cs file from the original project to the upgraded project

Comment: ok. i will give it a try. By the way what it is? some sort of Bug in VS2010  IDE?